# Ошибка подключения!

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Здравствуйте уважаемые ветераны PHP и обычные пользователи. Столкнулся с проблемой подключения, пишу Вам что бы разобраться как ее решить )

```
Ошибка !: SQLSTATE [HY000] [1045] Доступ запрещен для пользователя 'u052****' @ 'localhost' (с использованием пароля: YES)
```

Вот само подключение:

```
<?php

define("HOST",               "localhost");
define("USER",               "u052****_default");
define("PASSWORD",           "***********");
define("DB",                 "u052****_nameses");

?>
```

//------------

```
<?php
include "mysql.php";
$options = array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
);
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.HOST.';dbname='.DB.';', USER, PASSWORD, $options);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
?>
```

Столкнулся с такой ошибочкой при переходе в ЛК

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on boolean in /var/www/u052****/data/www/ucp.******.su/view/account.php on line 32
```

Comment: Ну собственно вам же все написали. Доступ запрещен для пользователя 'u052****'

Comment: Первая ошибка: нет доступа для пользователя БД. Вторая - в 32 строке файла account.php вы обращаетесь к методу rowCount() переменной, хранящей булево значение.

Comment: С хостом может быть связана первая ошибка?
Вторую как исправить? Не могу понять (